# How to Click a Drop Down Menu Element in a Table

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

EDIT:

I am interested in using the Selenium webdriver in Stata to download 4 files. The files are located on a [website](http://www.snim.rami.gob.mx/#) maintained by the Mexican Government (click on the “Descarga de Base de Datos” button on the left-hand side). Specifically, I am interested in downloading all of the files in the "Índice de Desarrollo Humano” (Human Development Index) drop down menu. This is the 5th drop down menu from the very bottom of the table. It has one file for the year 2000, 2005, 2010 and 2015.

I need to get Selenium to know that I want to click on: a) the dropdown menu to select the correct year, and b) the Excel button next to the drop down menu so I can download it. So far, using the full Xpath (included in my code) hasn't worked. First, I want to download the 2000 data in the Índice de Desarrollo Humano drop down menu, then click on 2005 in the drop down menu and download that dataset, and so on and so forth for the remaining two. So you can follow along with what I did, I’m attaching the code you can use to get to the point I’m at. I’m using Chrome, on Windows, and have Python version 3.9.0. Note that I'm using Stata, so Python users can delete the "python:" and "end" statements.

CODE:

```
python :

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import requests

# Changing Download Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences= {"download.default_directory": "D:/Articles/QueDif"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)


#browser exposes an executable file
#Through Selenium test we will invoke the executable file which will then #invoke actual browser

# Change this to your path for the webdriver.
cp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"


# Path of my WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cp, chrome_options=options)


# to maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

#get method to launch the URL
driver.get("http://www.snim.rami.gob.mx/#")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src='index2.html'] ")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Descarga de Base de Datos"))).click()


driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/select/option[2]").click


end
```

Comment: OP has modified the original Post, it was addressed correctly. Vote to close this this question cause it violates SO guidelines - "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever experiences a similar issue, I want to post the code that ended up working for me. On my end, this correctly downloaded all of the files I wanted (presumably this apporoach would work for the other files on the page, too). Here's my code:

```
python:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# Changing Download Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences= {"download.default_directory": "D:\Articles\QueDif"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

# Change this to your path for the webdriver.
cp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"

url = "http://www.snim.rami.gob.mx/#"


# Path of my WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cp, chrome_options=options)

stata: cls
# to maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

#get method to launch the URL
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

#Switches to the iframe to click the button
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src='index2.html'] ")))


#clicks the button of interest
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Descarga de Base de Datos"))).click()


# Import time to lazily force a pause on the script
import time
time.sleep(3)

# View all "option" tags within the desc8_anio ID
# This should just produce a list elements representing each drop-down element
print(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#desc8_anio > option"))

# Store the number of items for iterating
count_options = len( driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#desc8_anio > option") )

# Click on a single item from the drop down (note the number of the nth-child)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#desc8_anio > option:nth-child(2)").click()

#### PUT IT ALL TOGETHER INTO A LOOP
# Import time to lazily force a pause on the script
import time

# Iterate through range of numbers for count_options (+1), click 
# on appropriate button, and then download file
for i in range(1, count_options+1):
    print(i)
    
    # Dynamically change the nth-child(...) value to be the current value of "i"
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#desc8_anio > option:nth-child({})".format(i)).click()
    
    # Click on the excel button to download the file
    excel = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#prepdesc > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(11) > td:nth-child(6) > input")
    excel.click()
    
    # Pause for 1 second
    time.sleep(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the issue is `iframe`. You need to switch to iframe first then driver can interact with left side menu :

`CSS_SELECTOR` for iframe is this :

```
iframe[src='index2.html']
```

switch it like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src='index2.html'] ")))
```

and then click on `Descarga de Base de Datos` using the below code  :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Descarga de Base de Datos"))).click()
```

Once you are done with iframe switch back to default content like this :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the first half. Now an additional one if you don't mind. I've adjusted my code accordingly. Now I want to download the files for the Human Development Indices, the 5th box from the bottom. When I try and click on it as shown above, it also says that the xpath can't be found. Is this the same problem as before, with the iframes? Inspecting the pages source code, I can only find the iframe you mentioned above, so it doesn't seem like there's another form to switch to.

Comment: When I clicked on `Descarga de Base de Datos` I do not see `Human Development`.

Comment: My apologies, I should've translated it the first time. The drop down menu you're looking for is "Índice de Desarrollo Humano", which in English is Human Development index. My goal is to loop over these different excel files and download them. It's the fifth row from the bottom.

Comment: I can see 4 `Índice de Desarrollo Humano` in HTML Page source. All of them are basically hyperlinks. I am still having tough time figuring out where they exist in UI. And all 4 of them are under same iframe. So you do not have to switch to any other iframe or to default content.

Comment: Okay, so in that case, the final question is: how would I go about selecting the 2000...2005 excel files in the drop down menu for the section I mentioned, and download them? When I try to click on them with the modified syntax above, it returns the error "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="desc8_anio"]/option[1]"}" If they're all on the same frame, this should select the proper section of the drop down menu so that it can be downloaded, but it doesn't. @cruisepandey

Comment: @JaredGreathouse : I believe if there are more than 2K excel file in a drop down, How would you download them manually ? One by one right ? We can automate the same steps but having said that, is it really required to download 2K excel files for your use case ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233701/discussion-between-jared-greathouse-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: It's unethical to do what you did.. if you have any new concern, create a new ticket instead. I have downvoted your question cause it's unethical